# :After element positioning wrong only in IE :before element is correct

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for a local firm. We have a contact form that pops up over whatever page your on, accepts the information and then just allows you to stay on the current page you are viewing. Which works all well and good.

What I cannot figure out at the moment is why the `:after` element of the styling for the form behaves weird only in internet explorer.

[image: It looks like this in Chrome and Firefox.] The paper corners looks is rendered via CSS over the element that is the contact form.

[image: In IE it looks like this however.] It looks like this in IE10 and 11.

The CSS is as follows

```
    #contact-form{
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #0E0C1F;
background: #F0FBFB;
   }

    #contact-form:after {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid #fefefe;
top: -55px;
right: 666px;
box-shadow: 0px 7px 6px -9px black;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    }

   #contact-form:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 50px solid #fefefe;
top: 547px;
left: 666px;
box-shadow: 0px -7px 6px -9px black;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    }
```

As pointed out in one of my comments below I'm using [Magnific](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to render the initial popup and then styling it from there. By default the popup is set to `position: relative;` and so is the container the wraps around the form.

I modified my styled version of the `#contact-form` ID to contain `position: relative !important` just in the vent something odd was overwritting the already set `positions: relative;` Doing so did nothing to fix the form.

The class that wraps the form reads as follows:

`.white-popup-block{background:#FFF;padding:20px 30px 20px 30px;text-align:left;max-width:650px;margin:40px auto;position:relative}`

Changing the padding on the bottom does have some effect on making the `:after` element and paper edge lineup in IE but then it just overflows the positioning of the paper corner in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Which version of IE are you having trouble with? Also try giving `#contact-form` `relative:position`

Comment: @Jrod Tried that. Nothing. Also this is a problem on my station working with IE11 and appears on the other computers in the office which are using IE10. One or two might still be on 9.

Comment: It looks to me like the `:after` is working perfectly, but the spacing inside the form popup is different in IE, which makes it look like the `:after` element isn't positioned correctly.

Comment: Yes, `#contact-form` needs to be `position:relative`

Comment: @Paulie_D it is already `position: relative;` The [popup is created with Magnific.](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) which sets up the basics of the popup for you to be styled later. By default the #contact form and its container are set to `position: relative;` I modified my styled version of the ID to have `position: relative !imporant;` in the event something was overriding something weird only to have no change in the behavior.

Comment: You might want to indicate that by editing your question/code so we have all the relevant information.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Thumbs up on the position: relative on the parent container.

Comment: Yes, that should make the positioning values a lot simpler those seem much too high to be correct.

Comment: Position the `:after` using the `bottom` property instead of the `top`. @RevanProdigalKnight noted that the spacing looks different. Using bottom should work regardless of the height of the popup.

Comment: @Jrod it had not occurred to me but this is the correct answer. Everyone else had suggested setting position relative. It had always been set as position relative so that was never the issue. Placing the corner on the bottom from the bottom instead of working every position from the top is what eventually worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the `:after` using the `bottom` property to control the positioning regardless of the popup height difference that is caused by IE.